# Customizing the Detail Account Page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, page-layout, account

i am asked to create a customize standard account page and to add a component as shown in figure [image] he want to show some logos in account information as shown in the image.is this possible and how to correctly approach this .please suggest .

Answer (score 3):

See [How to use images in formula fields](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000007604&language=en_US) for a formula-only solution (no Visualforce required). You can also add Visualforce to the page by using code similar to the following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:image src="{!IF(something,'/images/image1.gif','/images/image2.gif)}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: its only for one image at a time .if there are multiple logo to show in the same field then how to approach the problem ??r u getting there three four logos in the same field.

Comment: is it possible to use svg or html in formula field ??

Comment: You can have as many fields as will compile into the formula (approximately 20, but your milage may vary). If this won't work, you can use a Visualforce page. Simply write the code as in the example, then go to the account layout, edit it, and add the Visualforce page to the layout.